# Android: recover an image which it has been loaded

Tags: android, image, caching

I want to load and scale an image from an URL in a imageView.

Then, when user touch that image, I want to load the image (without scale) in other imageView or webView for example.

The problem is that I don't want load image twice. The first time, it download in somewhere (cache?) and I want recover for not doing two request...

some example? suggestion?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should consider to load first just a thumbnail of the image and wait with downloading the real one until the user really wants to see it.

for caching see [LruChache](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/LruCache.html)

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial should help with caching: http://codehenge.net/blog/2011/06/android-development-tutorial-asynchronous-lazy-loading-and-caching-of-listview-images/

If you have lots of images, consider using an `LruCache`. It helps manage large amounts of cache data.